# What is a good method to compare the values with different sample sizes?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, regularization, overfitting, text-mining

I am performing text analysis on some social media posts and I have a list of words and corresponding engagement rates, such as the list below (a much shorter version of a long list). As you can see, words that show up in fewer posts can have a disproportionally high engagement rate compared to words that show up more frequently.

Is there a statistical best practice for handling the values of words with low posts counts so that I can build a better picture of words that generate the highest engagement? I.e. I wish to lower the value of words that show up in fewer posts. Thank you!

| word | post_count | engagement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| paired | 1 | 96.63% |
| glacier | 3 | 47.63% |
| visiting | 37 | 8.64% |
| exploring | 22 | 8.11% |
| bringing | 10 | 3.68% |

In answer to a question by  Aleksejs, I have also included an example of how the word-level engagement is calculated.

| Post | Reach | Engagement | Post Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Happy #GlobalWellnessDay! After the global pandemic, living better is no longer an option, it’s a necessity | 779760 | 20109 | 230 |
| We are very happy to share this year Design Award winners. | 54491 | 625 | 120 |

As "happy" shows up in these two posts, across these two posts I calculate the word-level engagement rate to be 20734/834251 = 2.49%.

Comment: In statistical jargon the problem you're having is "overfitting". The model is relying too strongly on data coming from very small samples. The ways we usually deal with this are "regularization". I don't know any to suggest in text analysis, but a naive idea could be to add 1 (or more) post_count with a small engagement (perhaps the average engagement over the whole dataset, or 0% engagement) to all words. That would bias the results towards the average (or towards 0), but the adjustment's size will diminish for larger post_counts.

Comment: What's an engagement rate? Or, more precisely, how can one know the engagement rate from only 1 post?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to have a look and respond!

@David – thanks. I will look into regularisation more. The data does have more words with much higher posts in the 000's but I wanted provide a short snippet as an example.

Comment: @Aleksejs Engagement is calculated on a word level. A post is tokenised into lemmas with a tally of engagements and reach for each lemma. So if 1 post featuring the word "getaway" got {engagement:10, reach:100} and another got {engagement:30, reach:1000} the engagement rate for that word would be 3.63% across both posts. The idea is that across 000's of posts we would build a good picture of which words generate engagement. Is this a good way to do it?

You're right. One post is not reliable. But a word that popped up in 15,000 posts would be reliable?

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite get it. Can you specify the formula to calculate engagement of a word given engagements and reaches of individual posts?

Comment: Sure. I updated the answer above to include a new table showing how the engagement rate is calculated. Does this help?